# Needing a simple circuit to switch a vacuum pump from a pressure switch at 4.5v

Tags: switches, dc-motor, battery-operated

I’m looking for some help to build a simple circuit to take a NO switch input and use this to drive a 3-5v vacuum pump.
The switch I’m using is open when the pressure has not been reached (Which is when I need the pump to operate), and closed when the pressure has been reached.
This circuit and the pump are running of 3x AA cells.
As it’s running on batteries I need the circuit to consume as little power as possible please. I’m sure the motor needs some fly back protection but not sure what’s appropriate.
I’m trying to keep the cost and part count down as well.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more details on the vacuum pump and the pressure switch?

Comment: The pumps are small brushed D.C. vacuum pumps. I have two I’m looking at, one is a 3v diaphragm pump which is okay to run at 5v (Koge KV08A - https://www.koge.com/product.php) and the other is a slightly larger 5v diaphragm pump happy to run down to 4v. Both will only need to intermittently operate.
Thanks for replying.

Comment: we also need specs on the pressure sensor, because you need some hysterises, and if the sensor doesnt have it already then adding it will be tricky (it would have to be time based hysterises rather than presure based hysterises)

Comment: It’s a pressure switch such as the Lefoo LFS02. There is some pneumatic hysteresis in the pneumatic system, but I I could possibly get circuits with aNd without electronic hysteresis that would allow me to experiment with both. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: It is always useful to: -  (1) include as much information as possible (eg motor start and run currents) (2)  Add any extra information that arises from comments to your question. Comments may be deleted and it is hard for people acquire information spread between comments and question. (3)  to supply as many links as available. || Note that 3 x AA alkaline cells will have voltages from 3V flat to 4.8V when new. 3 cells will be ar 1.33V each when Vout is 4V - a significant amount of energy will be unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch you're using has very little hysterisis, which isn't great for you, but you can still make it work. There are many different ways to do it, but I would say that the simplest is to use a schmitt trigger and some capacitors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmJh4x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What happens here is that the motor stays on until the target pressure is reached. At the target pressure (when the pressure switch activates), the motor will immediately turn off. The pressure switch will then deactivate and after about 7 seconds, the motor will turn back on until the target pressure is released, and so on. If you wanted the motor to continue for a bit after the target pressure was reached, you could change R1 to 10k and add a 100k resistor (R2) inbetween C1 and M2/R2. To increase the size of the delays, increase C1, or increase R2 (if you added it), or increase R1 (if you dont have an R2).

There are a few issues with this, mainly that the delays will change as the battery voltage changes (and as the temperature changes). The delay also wont be very accurate generally, as capacitors have quite wide tolerances, as does thie schmitt trigger.

If you really needed something more precise, it would probably be easiest to replace everything except the pressure sensor, M3 and D1 with a simple microcontroller.

Comment: Many thanks. Will this work a 4.5v from 3xAA, and also what diode would you recommend?

Comment: Yes, it will work with 3xAA. The limiting factor will be the minimum voltage of the schmitt trigger, which is 3V. You may want to change this for a different one if you find that your voltage is dipping below that. You will also need to add various decoupling capacitors on the power line, especially next to the schmitt trigger (1uF + 100nF) and the motor (10uF + 100nF). You can use any standard diode really, like 1N4001

Comment: Many thanks for this. Really appreciated... now to find someone to make the PCB 

Comment: If this answered your question, could you mark it as the answer

Comment: @Brian  I suggest that IF you want to use full battery energy you use BeB00's circuit (or similar) but operate it from 4 cells and place a low dropout regulator in the pump supply. The circuitry operates directly from battery with low quiescent current and the regulator is used only when the pump is running. OR a regulator could be used to operate the whole circuit if its quiescent current is low enough. (A circuit with say 100 uA quiescent current and no other usage will use up a set of AA alkaline cells in about 3 years.).